# Pie chart is not drawn when i create the data dynamically - flutter, google pie chart library

Tags: flutter, dart

Pie chart is not drawn when i create the data dynamically, but same is working fine when i create hardcoded values (i checked the dynamically created list, it has exact content as hardcoded one). here is my code below:

```
    static List<charts.Series<InvestmentPie, String>> _createSampleData(List<Investment> invList) {
        List<InvestmentPie> data = [];
        for(int i=0;i<invList.length;i++){
          double chartVal = 0.0;
          List<AssetClass> assetClass = invList[i].assetClasses;
          for(int j=0;j<assetClass.length;j++){

            AssetClass assetCl = assetClass[j];
            chartVal += (assetCl.allocation * invList[i].valValue1) / 100;
          }
          Color clr = Colors.primaries[Random().nextInt(Colors.primaries.length)];

 String nm = invList[i].stockName;
          int nms = chartVal.round();

          InvestmentPie inv1 = new InvestmentPie(nm, nms,
              charts.Color.fromHex(code: '#${clr.value.toRadixString(16)}'));
          data.add(inv1);
        }

        Color clr = Colors.primaries[Random().nextInt(Colors.primaries.length)];

        List<InvestmentPie> data1 = [
          new InvestmentPie('BCP Protected Portfolio Bond - Growth Version', 270,
              charts.Color.fromHex(code: '#${clr.value.toRadixString(16)}')),
          new InvestmentPie('BCP Film Finance Scheme 2 (March 2019)', 411,
              charts.Color.fromHex(code: '#${clr.value.toRadixString(16)}')),
          new InvestmentPie('BCP Protected Portfolio Bond - Growth Plus Version',
              285, charts.Color.fromHex(code: '#${clr.value.toRadixString(16)}')),
          new InvestmentPie(
              'BCP Global Equity Absolute Return Bond 7 - Growth Plus Version',
              342,
              charts.Color.fromHex(code: '#${clr.value.toRadixString(16)}')),
        ];


        return [
          new charts.Series<InvestmentPie, String>(
            id: 'Investments',
            domainFn: (InvestmentPie investment, _) => investment.stockName,
            measureFn: (InvestmentPie investment, _) => investment.investmentValue,
            colorFn: (InvestmentPie investment, _) => investment.barColor,
            labelAccessorFn: (InvestmentPie investment, _) => investment.stockName,

            data: data,
          )
        ];
      }
```

in the above code if i use the 'data1' then i am getting the pie chart, if i change it to 'data' - then it showing empty chart as attached. I am sure the issue is with creation of my data list but dont know what it will be the issue.

[image]

Comment: When you create `inv1` you are using fixed values instead on `nm` and `nms`

Comment: @RichardHeap i just tried to hardcode and see anything coming or not, but even hard coded values also not working. I just edited and reposted my question.